# Dice with an average roll of zero?

Tags: game-accessories

Are there dice that have both positive and negative numbers, where the average result is zero?  I'm imagining a die labeled something like: -2, -1, 0, +1, +2.  I feel like I've seen dice like this, but I'm not sure what they'd be called or how to find them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Probably the most commonly available ones are called **Fudge dice**, as used in the Fudge/FATE roleplaying games.

A Fudge die is a six-sided die with the following sides: minus, minus, blank, blank, plus, plus.

Games generally have players rolling a couple of Fudge dice together and adding them up, which creates a curved probability distribution centered around zero. 3dF, for example, gives you a range from -3 to +3, with 0 as the mean, median, and mode.

[This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fudge_%28role-playing_game_system%29#Fudge_dice) has more information.

Answer (score 6):

You could take any two normal dice of different colors and denote one as the positive die and one as the negative die.

Comment: Yup. This gives a triangular distribution rather than a bell curve approximation, but it is quick, easy to find dice for, and is close enough that it's often suggested as a drop-in replacement (using d6s) for the harder-to-acquire four Fudge dice. +1

Comment: If you lack dice of different colors, you can just roll them both and flip a coin (heads positive, tails negative) or a third die (even positive, tails negative). A bit more of a pain, but considering the absurdly high number of plain Jane white dice floating around my house, it would be reasonable.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie If you want a bell curve approximation, just take a hundred dice instead of two.

Comment: @JoeZeng [50d6 - 50d6](http://anydice.com/program/1e6a) actually gets you a narrow bell with long flat tails—not a nice distribution at all. For a nice bell curve approximation you only need [2d6 - 2d6](http://anydice.com/program/c89). Everyone knows that adding more dice gives a nicer bell when you're summing them, but that intuition absolutely does not hold when subtraction is involved.

Comment: Whoops. I forgot that about subtraction.

Comment: In that case, use a hundred dice and subtract 350 instead.